# visual studio 2019 crystal report, how to know the unit of measurement for position height, left

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

1. as the image attached, I guess the unit of height, left, top, widht is TWIPs, but how can I verify this? I cannot find any place to show the unit it is used.
2. how can I change the height, left...., width to another unit like px, mm ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you see for the Position properties are measured in "twips".  There are 1440 twips in 1 inch.